# antlr nongreedy operator fails to match a valid input

Tags: antlr, antlr4

The following rule in antlr4 will not work for a valid input:

```
testSimple
    : 'name' 'eq' WORD+?  .*? NEWLINE

WORD:  ~[ \t\f\r\n]+ ;
```

The input is :

```
name eq John Tom Allen notAName
```

The error is:

```
line 1:8 no viable alternative at input 'John'
```

I know using nongreedy operator has some limitations, like the 'first match wins' rule afterwards.  And the rule is particularly ambiguous. But shouldn't it at least match the input in at least one way?

Answer (score 1):

Try parsing with an explicit EOF symbol on the end of your entry rule. For example:

```
startTestSimple
    :   testSimple EOF
    ;
```

Without the explicit EOF in place, the algorithm may fail to find a viable alternative in some cases. [Issue #118](https://github.com/antlr/antlr4/issues/118) describes one case where this is a problem; unfortunately the performance impact of the known solution is quite large, so we won't be including it in the ANTLR 4 runtime until we come up with an alternate solution.